# Group a subset of values into a list of single row per key, but add None if true on a condition

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have the following data that I want to conduct groupby on:

```
Key Prod Val 
A     a   1
A     b   0
B     a   1
B     b   1
B     d   1
C     a   0
C     b   0
```

I want to group the table so I have a single row per each key, **A, B and C**, and a list containing the prod values corresponding to the key. But the element should only be in the list of there's an indicator of 1 for the corresponding val. If it's completely 0 for the entire subset of a key, than the key should just get a **none** value. Here's the result I'm looking for using the same e.g. above:

```
Key List 
A    [a]   
B    [a, b, d]   
C     None
```

What's the most efficient way to perform this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df.query('Val == 1').groupby('Key')['Prod'].agg(lambda x: list(x)).reindex(df.Key.unique())
```

Output:

```
Key
A          [a]
B    [a, b, d]
C          NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: Brilliant! You just saved me a lot on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I think just making a new dataframe would be easiest:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['list'], index = set(df1.Key))

for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    df2.loc[i, 'list'] = []

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    key = df1.loc[i, 'key']
    if df1.loc[i, 'val'] == 1:
        df2.loc[key, 'list'].append(df1.loc[i, 'prod'])
```

Comment: I should probably clarify that I'm looking for a non-loop solution. But neverthless +1 for the effort and being the first response.

Comment: Thanks, and in that case I'm going to follow along because I'm also curious to see if there's a vectorized solution to this.

Comment: Yeah it's a tricky manipulation. Eager to see how someone else might approach this.